Getting a timeout only in GitHub Actions when trying to use SQL Server with TestContainers
This is my first time trying to use TestContainer. I am using it to make sure the tests run on a fresh database. This works with Docker Desktop locally and runs quite fast. I am now testing to see how it will work in a CI pipe in the cloud.
However, after 5 minutes of the following is clearly fails. I can extend the timeout but don't believe this will help as the tests run so fast locally.

[testcontainers.org 00:05:45.93] Execute "/opt/mssql-tools/bin/sqlcmd -Q SELECT 1;" at Docker container

Googling everywhere isn't helping. Here is my YAML file.
name: Run Tests 

on:

  workflow_dispatch:
  push:
    branches:
      - main

jobs:
  run-tests:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest

    steps:
      - uses: actions/checkout@v3

      - name: Setup .NET
        uses: actions/setup-dotnet@v3
        with:
          dotnet-version: '8.0.x'

      - name: Restore
        run: dotnet restore ./ExempPlaygroundApp.sln

      - name: Build
        run: dotnet build ./ExempPlaygroundApp.sln --no-restore

      - name: Test
        run: dotnet test ./ExempPlaygroundApp.sln --no-build

Any help is appreciated.

Titles are for introducing your problem, not for repeating tags. Please do take a moment to write a meaningful title.

I thought that title was meaningful as it explained the problem and the technology being used. I’m sorry you didn’t think it did. Happy to accept the criticism if you provide an example that brings more value without being overly verbose.

Looks like this issue might not be code related. Just found this issue from yesterday - https://github.com/testcontainers/testcontainers-dotnet/issues/1220

See [ask]; which explains what a good title should look like.

That looks like what I have now.

This was a newly introduced bug with the Docker images being used. See this GitHub issue for more information.
I downgraded from mcr.microsoft.com/mssql/server:2022-latest to mcr.microsoft.com/mssql/server:2022-CU13-ubuntu-22.04 in order to work around the issue.
